# Sum even numbers within list of lists after eliminating specific items

Tags: python

Task at hand:

> Implement the function `sum_even(xs)` that takes a list of list of ints `xs` and returns the
> sum of the even numbers but skips the numbers on the first row and the first column of
> `xs`. You're not allowed to modify `xs`. You can't use any built-in function or method except
> `int`, `str`, `range` and `len`.
>
> `sum_even([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) --> 14`

This is where I am at:

```
xs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
def sum_even(xs):        
    first = (xs[0])
    second = (xs[1])
    third = (xs[2])
    first.clear()
    for i in second[1:]:
            print(i)        
    for i in third[1:]:
            print(i)
    return(sum_even(xs))
    result = 0 
    for i in xs:
        if not i % 2:
            result += i
         
    print(result)
```

Lines 1-10 return the right values:

```
5
6
8
9
None
```

Now I need to sum all of the evens to get 14. Should I create a new list from the results after line 10 and then create a simple sum function?

Comment: This seems to be an exercise in using slices. Slice `xs` such as to start with the second row, and then loop over these, slicing each row such as to start with the second column to give the cells that you should loop over inside an inner loop. Within this inner loop, use the even numbers to increment a total that you initialise at the start. This leads to a solution that is not many lines of code, with nested `for` loops. You should not assume any particular number of rows in `xs`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an exercise to learn how to use `range`. Review [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

```py
def sum_even(xs):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, len(xs)):
        for j in range(1, len(xs[i])):
            if not xs[i][j] % 2:
                sum += xs[i][j] 
    return sum
```